# facebook like button count reset - without app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have been using the Facebook like button on our site for a few years now. It worked fine until a few days ago. The count has reset - it was above 400, and now the count is showing 4 - https://www.lifedirect.co.nz/

We are not using Facebook app, just directly using URL and iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lifedirect.co.nz%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="fbiframe" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Also used meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lifedirect.co.nz"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="LifeDirect - Quote &amp; Compare Insurance"/>
```

Maybe this is unrelated - we have changed our site from http => https a few months ago. Right after the change, the count is showing 0. We have to use the meta tag above, and change the "href" attribute to show the correct count. And it worked fine until a few days ago.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I used the URL CBroe provided (thanks for that!), and did some testing. HTTP version of our site has 469 likes, and HTTPS version has 4 likes. Is there anyway to transfer the 469 likes to HTTPS version of the site?

Comment: Yes http and https are two different sites

Comment: I understand that. That's the reason we used meta tag for the site. It worked fine under https (showing 400+) until a few days ago - which I don't know what other cause can it be. Maybe if someone liked the https site, the stats will reset?

Comment: Your site is automatically redirecting to the HTTPS version, but since the `og:url` points to the HTTP version, that causes a redirect error: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lifedirect.co.nz You need to _not_ redirect to HTTPS, when the FB scraper requests the HTTP version, but instead serve the OG meta data under the HTTP URL. You can [identify the scraper by its User Agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo).

Comment: Thanks for replying. We can't really host the site under both HTTP and HTTPS. It has to be only HTTPS. Is there anything we can do, under this condition (we can change other things like og:url and etc.)

Comment: just use your old http url on the og metatags and you're done.

Comment: Yeh, that was half working until a few days ago. By half working I meant it showed the count for old URL, and that count never increases any more. And it can be broken again upon some unknown condition. Can only go back to old count if I use the URL CBroe pointed out to manually crawl our site.